# Is Max-2SAT with exactly 3 occurrences per variable APX-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, satisfiability, approximation, 2-sat

The Max-2SAT problem asks if at least k clauses of a 2CNF formula can be satisfied.

The Max-2SAT(at-most-3) problem is the restriction in which every variable occurs in 
*at most* 3 clauses (counting positive and negative occurrences together).  It is known that this problem is APX-hard, the reference being 
[this book](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540654315).  However, I can't access the book, so I can't look at the details.

The Max-2SAT(exactly-3) problem is the restriction in which every variable occurs in 
*exactly* 3 clauses, i.e. no variable occurs only twice.
From [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-48523-6_17), I believe the problem is NP-hard.  But I don't know if it's also APX-hard.
Is it?  Does it follows from the "at-most-3" case?
If not, I'd like to know how many of the n variables occur only twice, and not three times.

Comment: Have you tried coming up with an algorithm and/or a reduction?

Comment: I did try to reduce the "at-most-3" case to the "exactly-3" case, by attempting to add 1 occurrence for the 2-occurrence variables and incorporating new dummy variables.  That does not behave too well however.  Other ideas are welcome.  Also, if anyone knows about the cited APX-hardness reduction, I'd be happy to see it.